# Isp Output of NASA CEA

Tags: rocketry

I have 2 questions related to NASA CEA's Isp values in the output file.

1. When looking through the output of NASA's CEA tool, I am trying to understand the difference between its "Ivac" output and its "Isp" output. What is the difference between these two outputs?
2. While the concept of a vacuum Isp makes sense to me, I don't understand why it is output in the context of  the inputs I put in; I gave the CEA code a finite value Pc/Pe number, meaning Pe was not 0. So what is Ivac mean in this context?

Comment: How does the program define those outputs?

Comment: That is what I am here to find out. There is one pdf online that has a table of these symbols, but it describes Ivac as "Vacuum Isp" (I already figured that much out) and it defines Isp as "specific impulse". Again, not helpful.